# custom redirect on wordpress

Tags: url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to create a custom rewrite rule that will take in a second query string.

current: http://mysite.com/daily-deals/?category=alldeals

I would like it to be: http://mysite.com/daily-deals/alldeals/

I have tried the solution below but it doesnt seem to work.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^daily-deals/(.*)$ index.php?page_id=508&category=$1 [L,NC]

</IfModule>
RewriteEngine Off


# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**Idea #1**

```
RedirectMatch 301 daily-deals/(.*)$ [[GENERATED URL WHERE YOU WANT TO REDIRECT]]
```

**Idea #2**

You could make the redirection with a 
[Wordpress redirection plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/)